# drop down menu background changes to black in Android Apps

Tags: android, css, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working in an **Android** application using **jQueryMobile and Phonegap**.
My application is almost done and tested in different devices. But when I test in **HTC 500 desire**; I found an issue in drop-down list.
**drop down menu background changes to black**. But I couldn't find such an error in other devices.

[image]

Anybody can help me to find-out why this issue is happening??
Still I didn't get a solution for this. please help ... `:(`

Comment: @Mohsen : Yeah... Black or Gray whatever it is.. do u know how we can solve this?

Comment: When I install another jQueryMobile Application in same device; this error is there.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work CSS for devices but I think this code may help you:

```
#YourDropDownID * {
   background-color:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Ohk.. Mohsen
Let me check with this !